# GROUP BY with nested case expression - is there better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, case

SQL server 2012

I am taking fees received and multiplying them by different factors based on how long the Client has been a Client.  The `group by` clause is fairly straight forward.  However, my `select` gets awkward when I want to use this criteria in different ways:

```
select mp.professionals
    ,case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) then 'New' else 'Old' end age -- straight forward
    ,case (case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) then 'New' else 'Old' end) -- nested case
        when 'New' then sum(fees) * 0.5
        when 'Old' then sum(fees) * 0.25
        else 0
    end Credit
    ,case (case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) then 'New' else 'Old' end) -- nested case
        when 'New' then 'Welcome!'
        when 'Old' then 'Thank you for being a long-time Client!'
    end Greeting
from mattersprofessionals mp
inner join matters m on m.matters = mp.matters
inner join stmnledger sl on sl.matters = mp.matters
group by mp.professionals, case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) then 'New' else 'Old' end
```

I suppose I should mention this is a simplified version of my actual `case` statements.

I was hoping there was a way to group by `sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate)` as a boolean or something so I don't have to do the nested case expressions.

I know I could do a sub-query on the basic case and then do more case expressions in the outer query. But that's just rearranging the same nested case concept.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a nested case expression. Your query is simple compared to many of mine.

Comment: Ha!  I'm sure my heavily simplified example is indeed very simple compared to many of yours.  lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the values are calculated directly from the row I tend to use `cross apply` for this as it is more concise than adding a derived table/CTE whose only purpose is to define a column alias but still needs to project out the remaining columns and contain a `FROM`.

This is not an option for expressions that reference window functions or aggregate functions but will work fine here.

```
select mp.professionals
    ,ca.age -- straight forward
    ,case ca.age -- nested case
        when 'New' then sum(fees) * 0.5
        when 'Old' then sum(fees) * 0.25
        else 0
    end Credit
    ,case ca.age -- nested case
        when 'New' then 'Welcome!'
        when 'Old' then 'Thank you for being a long-time Client!'
    end Greeting
from mattersprofessionals mp
inner join matters m on m.matters = mp.matters
inner join stmnledger sl on sl.matters = mp.matters
cross apply (select case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) then 'New' else 'Old' end) ca(age)
group by mp.professionals, ca.age
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and see how it works.  I've never used cross/outer apply -- it'll be an adventure.  Do you expect this to have any performance difference?

Comment: Not between this and the derived table/CTE. Both approaches make it more likely than the original code that the common sub expression is only evaluated once so may save a bit of CPU but unlikely to be noticeable

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the query a little by pre-computing the `case` expression in a subquery:

```
select
    professionals,
    age,
    sum(fees) * case age 
        when 'New' then 0.5 
        when 'Old' then 0.25 
        else 0 
    end credit,
    case age 
        when 'New' then 'Welcome' 
        when 'Old' then 'Thank you for being a long-time Client!' 
    end greeting
from (
    select 
        mp.professionals,
        case when sl.stmndate < dateadd(year, 3, m.qClientOpenDate) 
            then 'New' 
            else 'Old' 
        end age 
    from mattersprofessionals mp
    inner join matters m on m.matters = mp.matters
    inner join stmnledger sl on sl.matters = mp.matters
) t
group by professionals, age
```

Note: the `else` branch in the `fees` calculation is probably never reached (since `age` always takes either value `'New'` or `'Old'`).

Comment: I mentioned this option in my question.  Do you think it'll perform better?  I doubt it but suppose I can test it.

Comment: I figured someone would point out that spurious `else` branch!  I was just trying to make my simplified example look a little more impressive.

Comment: aggregation is on sum(fees) in this simplified example.

Comment: @avery_larry: I would expect identical performance to your query (SQL Server should be able to optimize away the subquery anyway). This is more of a syntactical sugar that makes the query easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Technically I think the answer to my question is "No".  There isn't a way to group by the boolean portion of a `case` statement so it can be used in various ways within the `select`.

I upvoted GMB's and Martin Smith's answers as they are helpful and informative.  I am playing with the cross apply, a learning experience for sure.