# Avoid retyping column names in chained CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Sample Data**

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tmp
CREATE TABLE #Tmp(id INT NOT NULL, date_time DATETIME NOT NULL, val1 INT, val2 INT)
INSERT INTO #Tmp 
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01 12:00:00.00', 1, 2),
       (2, '2020-01-01 13:00:00.00', 1, 2)
```

**Problem**

Suppose that I want to do some (`n > 1`) calculations based on a column. However, I need to transform this column before hand (for instance cast it from `DATETIME` to `DATE`). I can easily use a chained CTE like this:

```sql
WITH trafo (date_only) AS (
   SELECT CAST(date_time as DATE) AS date_only 
     FROM #Tmp
 ), calc (next_week, prev_week) AS (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, date_only) AS next_week
          , DATEADD(DAY, - 7, date_only) AS prev_week 
     FROM trafo
 )
SELECT * 
  FROM calc
```

In this way I have to write `CAST(date_time as DATE)` only once and do not have to repeat it in the `DATEADD` part (I am aware that this `CAST` is not needed in this special case, but that is not the point, it should merely illustrate that I need to do some sort of transformation).

However, if I want to keep other columns as well, I need to copy it in every `WITH` clause, which becomes quite tedious (especially if you have quite some columns and if you [want to avoid `SELECT *`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4119/why-you-should-avoid-select--in-sql-server-tsql-code/)):

```sql
WITH trafo (id, date_only, val1, val2) AS (
   SELECT id
          , CAST(date_time as DATE) AS date_only
          , val1
          , val2 
     FROM #Tmp
 ), calc (id, next_week, prev_week, val1, val2) AS (
   SELECT id
          , DATEADD(DAY, 7, date_only) AS next_week
          , DATEADD(DAY, - 7, date_only) AS prev_week 
          , val1
          , val2
     FROM trafo
 )
SELECT * 
  FROM calc
```

I could select only the relevant columns in the first `WITH` clause and `JOIN` them back to the original table:

```sql
WITH trafo (id, date_only) AS (
   SELECT id
          , CAST(date_time as DATE) AS date_only 
     FROM #Tmp
 ), calc (id, next_week, prev_week, val1, val2) AS (
   SELECT trafo.id
          , DATEADD(DAY, 7, date_only) AS next_week
          , DATEADD(DAY, - 7, date_only) AS prev_week
          , val1
          , val2 
     FROM trafo
     JOIN #Tmp
       ON #Tmp.id = trafo.id
 )
SELECT * 
  FROM calc
```

But this seems not a very smart (in terms of performance)  idea to me (assuming that selecting is cheaper than joining).

**Question**

How should I approach this problem when I want

a. a good performance*

b. as little repetition in my code as possible?

---

* I know this depends on the real use case, but I mean it in a sense of avoiding unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular scenario seems to be ideal case of usage chained `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
WITH trafo (id, date_only, val1, val2) AS (
   SELECT id
          , CAST(date_time as DATE) AS date_only
          , val1
          , val2 
     FROM #Tmp
 ), calc (id, next_week, prev_week, val1, val2) AS (
   SELECT id
          , DATEADD(DAY, 7, date_only) AS next_week
          , DATEADD(DAY, - 7, date_only) AS prev_week 
          , val1
          , val2
     FROM trafo
 )
SELECT * 
  FROM calc
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT  t.id
      , t.val1
      , t.val2
      , s1.date_only
      , s2.next_week
      , s2.prev_week
FROM #Tmp t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(t.date_time as DATE) AS date_only) AS s1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, s1.date_only) AS next_week,
                    DATEADD(DAY, - 7, s1.date_only) AS prev_week) AS s2
```

Answer (score 2):

The columns that you select in the CTEs (or subqueries) really have no bearing on performance.  Let the optimizer do the work.  So, you can do:

```
WITH trafo AS (
      SELECT t.*, CAST(date_time as DATE) AS date_only
      FROM #Tmp t
     ),
     calc AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             DATEADD(DAY, 7, date_only) AS next_week,
             DATEADD(DAY, - 7, date_only) AS prev_week 
      FROM trafo
     )
SELECT . . .    -- whatever columns you want here
FROM calc;
```

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that in some cases it is ok to use `SELECT *`?

Comment: @thothal - yes. Inside a CTE is fine. It is the final `SELECT` from the CTE that you need to be careful to only `SELECT` the columns you need. SQL Server can look at the final columns that *are* actually needed and doesn't need to select columns that are ultimately unused. But that said [I would use `APPLY` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61624107/73226)

Comment: @thothal. . . Yes, of course.  Within a query it is fine.  It is fine for ad-hoc queries.  It is a bad idea to define result sets in views, stored procedures, stored functions, and scheduled "production" code.